# What is the New Update Of Notifications in Android

Tags: android

I am using Notification in my Android Application.

```
Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.iconmain, Title1, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

In this I have Stricke words on Notification. Please help me that New Updates of Notification in android.

Comment: Can you please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html),

> Notification(int icon, CharSequence tickerText, long when)
>
> *This constructor was deprecated in API level 11. Use Notification.Builder
>   instead.*

Try using `Notification.Builder`:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
         .setContentTitle(Title1)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconmain)
         .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
         .build();
```

However, from [Notifications guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification):

> **Required notification contents**
>
> A Notification object must contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
> - A title, set by setContentTitle()
> - Detail text, set by setContentText()

So, you still need to add `.setContentText()` to the builder.